# CodeChef ATM Easy level : Uses Casting,Conditionals. Code not being accepted

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, conditional-statements, floating-point-conversion

I have a little doubt about **casting** in C. The following problem deals with basic *casting and/or conditionals* logic.

So, I've just started on solving basic problems on CodeChef to make learning to code interesting, and I'm trying to solving the following "easy" problem: ( http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST ).

I believe I should also quote the question here for the SO community:

> Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will
>   only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's
>   account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction
>   (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank
>   charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted
>   transaction.
>
> **Input** Positive integer 0 < X <= 2000 - the amount of cash which Pooja wishes to withdraw. Nonnegative number 0<= Y <= 2000 with two
>   digits of precision - Pooja's initial account balance.
>
> **Output** Output the account balance after the attempted transaction, given as a number with two digits of precision. If there is not enough
>   money in the account to complete the transaction, output the current
>   bank balance.
>
> **Example** - **Successful Transaction** *Input*: 30 120.00 
>   *Output*: 89.50
>
> **Example - Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)** *Input*: 42 120.00 > *Output*: 120.00
>
> **Example - Insufficient Funds** *Input*: 300 120.00
>   *Output*:120.00

I thought as to **how to do this via casting integers to float ?**. I'm aware of the approach of *defining float variables*, as seen in the solutions submitted by others, (i.e. to declare balance as float type), but I'd still like to know *why can't this way?* (to declare balance as int and cast it to float later).

The code is compiling & executing fine on local IDE, but not being accepted. So am I going wrong anywhere?

Here's the mighty-simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int amt , bal ;
 float result;
 scanf("%d %d", &amt, &bal );
 if( ( 0 < amt <= 2000 ) && ( 0 <= bal <= 2000 ) ) //CORRECTED.SEE EDIT.
 {
    if ( ( amt % 5 !=0 ) || ( bal <= amt+1) )
    {
        result=(float)bal;
        printf("%.2f",result);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        result = (float) (bal-amt-0.50);
        printf("%.2f",result);
    }
}   
return 0;
}
```

So kindly tell me if the logic is wrong somewhere.

EDIT: I changed my relational operators to 'if((amt>0)&&(amt<=2000)&&(bal>=0)&&(bal<=2000))', but still no effect. It's still displaying Wrong Answer...

Comment: do you even C? Break down your relational expressions at line 6.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Changed. Here's the updated code on ideone: http://ideone.com/2dmCvC

Comment: what kind of error? give me an example

Comment: It simply says "Wrong Answer" @kiviak

Comment: @Aman Arora    I have changed my answer, maybe it works

Answer (score 1):

```
  0 < amt <= 2000
```

No, that is not how you use relational operators in `C`. You need to break it down in two separate condition check.

Something like

```
if ( (0 < amt) && (amt <= 2000))....
```

Similarly for other occurrences.

Comment: Hi.. Did the change... still not accepting.... http://www.codechef.com/submit/HS08TEST/

Comment: @AmanArora sorry the link is not accessible by me. can you use http://ideone.com instead to show the code?

Comment: @AmanArora looks fine for me. Maybe something specific check with that website.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if( ( 0 < amt <= 2000 ) && ( 0 <= bal <= 2000 ) )
```

to:

```
if((amt>0)&&(amt<=2000)&&(bal>=0)&&(bal<=2000))
```

and `bal` should be float

---

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     int amt  ;
     float result,bal;
     scanf("%d %f", &amt, &bal );
    if((amt>0)&&(amt<=2000)&&(bal>=0)&&(bal<=2000)) //CORRECTED.SEE EDIT.
     {
        if ( ( amt % 5 !=0 ) || ( bal < amt+0.5) )
        {
            result=bal;
            printf("%.2f",result);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            result = bal-amt-0.50;
            printf("%.2f",result);
        }
    }   
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The whole point is that I want to input balance as an integer data type... It's working this way, but can it work with "balance" as int type, with casting ?